# How can I make my website send email after checking captcha

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to setup a service for my friend where he will post an email request from his site to mine with html form tag and then my site will request a captcha check it's valid then send him the email but I'm not sure how to

I tried some online options but I can't find anything that will request the captcha then redirect to send the message check it's valid then send it

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? Please post the code you're having issues with. This isn't a place where we code stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

after verification of captcha. then redirect to page you want.